# Definition of base class destructor not needed?

Tags: c++

In all the examples I have seen about polymorphism the destructor of the base class is `virtual` and it is defined with an empty body.

I am trying to get my head around this: why does it have to be an empty body? Why doesn't it work if the method is just declared as `virtual` but not defined with an emtpy body? Wouldn't it be implemented then by the default destructor? Or the fact that it's being declared as `virtual` supresses even the default definition and forces to explicitly define the body?

This is what I mean:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual void f();
    virtual ~A() {}
}

class B : public A {
public:
    ~B() {
        // destroy whatever
    }
}
```

Why can't  `~A()` be declared just like this `virtual ~A();` without definition?

Also, why does it have to be defined like that (with the empty body) in abstract classes? I have tried to declare the destuctor of an abstract class like this `virtual ~A() = 0` and the compiler didn't let me do that.

Comment: Please see the discussion here, this provides a very thorough explanation of virtual destructor behavior https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors

Comment: @Cyber I already saw that post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why can't `~A()` be declared just like this `virtual ~A();` without definition?

Because a function that isn't defined can't be called. Simple as that. If you don't *declare* the destructor, the compiler implicitly *defines* one. But if you provide a *declaration* yourself then the compiler no longer provides a *definition*. You can explicitly give it the default definition in C++11 though.

```
virtual ~A() = default;
```

> Also, why does it have to be defined like that (with the empty body) in abstract classes? I have tried to declare the destuctor of an abstract class like this `virtual ~A() = 0` and the compiler didn't let me do that.

Same reason. As long as a destructor is called, it needs to have a definition, just like any other function. Normally a pure virtual function is never called, but destructors are an exception. You will have to provide a definition.

```
class A {
// ...
    virtual ~A() = 0; // declare destructor as pure virtual
};
// ...
A::~A() {} // define destructor
```

Comment: Usually one would assume that providing a destructor in a class that inherits from `A` should provide a definition for a `virtual ~A() = 0`, but this is not the case since a destructor cannot be overwritten, just extended.

Comment: So for an abstract class the definition of a destructor is needed, I understand? That doesn't make sense. If the class if abstract that means there won't be any instance of the class, so no object will need to be destructed, then we don't need a destructor.

Comment: @dabadaba When an object is destroyed, base class destructors are called, even if the base class is abstract.

Answer (score 1):

The destructor must have a body because it is called when the object is destroyed. Every time a derived object is destroyed, the last step is to call the base class's destructor. Without a body, the linker cannot find a definition of that destructor and the call fails, just like with normal functions not having definitions.

It's entirely possible (and necessary barring some obscure usage) to give a pure virtual destructor a body:

```
class Foo {
public:
    virtual ~Foo() = 0;
};

Foo::~Foo() {} //pre-C++11
Foo::~Foo() = default; //for an empty body with some benefits; C++11 and on
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't declare a destructor at all, the compiler generates one, but if you declare one, it suppresses the automatic generation, so you have to define it as well or you'll get an unresolved-symbol error at link time.

In C++11, you can declare the destructor as virtual but still have the compiler generate its implementation:

```
virtual ~Foo() = default;
```

The base class's destructor has to be defined somehow (even if it's empty) because derived classes' destructors implicitly call it at the end.  It doesn't make sense to have a pure-virtual destructor; derived classes may define their own destructors, but they can't define the *base* class's destructor.